# Element is not located selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I have selenium script that basic goal to put location in input tag and click on search button and open result page but I have problem in finding input and search button 
the script is below

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def search_location():
    for typ in TYPESOFR:
        for loc in LOCATIONS:
            MAINBROWSER.get(typ)
            elm = WebDriverWait(MAINBROWSER, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'localisation')))         
            location = MAINBROWSER.find_element_by_id("localisation")
            location.click()
            location.send_keys(loc)
            search = MAINBROWSER.find_element_by_xpath('.//button[@class="sendsearch btn-blue"]')
            MAINBROWSER.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search)

def main():
    search_location()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Links of types of real estates
    TYPESOFR = [
        'https://www.immoweb.be/nl/immo/huis/te-huur',
        'https://www.immoweb.be/nl/immo/appartement/te-huur',
        'https://www.immoweb.be/nl/immo/handelspand/te-huur',
        'https://www.immoweb.be/nl/immo/kantoor/te-huur',
        'https://www.immoweb.be/nl/immo/industrie/te-huur',
        'https://www.immoweb.be/nl/immo/garage/te-huur',
        'https://www.immoweb.be/nl/immo/ander/te-huur',]

    LOCATIONS = ['9000', '2000', '1000']


    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # Disable image loading on page it will load page faster
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    MAINBROWSER = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)

    # MAINBROWSER = webdriver.Firefox()

    # BROWSER = webdriver.Chrome()
    main()
```

code is basically do is get one by one URL from `TYPESOFR` list and opens the link and get one by one locations from `LOCATIONS` list and put it in the input tag and then click on search button
and follow the steps until loop completes

I have tried in both Chrome and Firefox gives both same error that element is not located

Comment: Which element is not located -- you have a couple of lookups in your code. Also, can you post a sample of the html that has the element? We have nothing to verify against.

Comment: `https://www.immoweb.be/nl/immo/huis/te-huur` this is the url and there is iframe `id="IWEB_IFRAME_ID_SEARCH"` it has a page that contains input tage and id is `id="localisation"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is iframe tag in html so need to use switch_to function of web driver

in above case it is used like this

```
# Switching to searh iFrame
MAINBROWSER.switch_to.frame(MAINBROWSER.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="IWEB_IFRAME_ID_SEARCH"]'))

# no input tag can be located by existing line
location = MAINBROWSER.find_element_by_id("localisation")
# ....... other logics ........
```